# Can't add HKCU entries via GroupPolicy Preferences

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

2008 R2, XP and W7 64 bit workstations.

Trying to add/modify two registry entries for Lync2010 for each user. Created using GP Management, User Configuration, Preferences, Registry.

If the two registry entries already exist, then the policy works correctly. If they don't exist, nothing changes. GPReults reports it was successful. If I import the .reg file manually, it also works, so I don't believe it is a rights issue.

I have tried the Update, Create, and Replace as the Action.

I am not familiar with ADM templates, is that the only way to do it?

Comment: Preferences work great in my experience.  Did you use the wizard for building your preferences?  I find that is usually a lot easier then trying to manually create prefs.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Zoredache, GPP usually work just fine, and AFAIK they're the only way to create registry keys/values without having to resort to scripts. The `Update` action should do what you want (update an existing key/value, and create it if it's missing).

- If the client is Windows XP, did you install the [client side extensions](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3628)?
- Did you run `gpupdate /force`?
- Did you reboot the machine (just to make sure)? I've seen preferences not being applied until after a `gpupdate /force` with a subsequent reboot.
- Do you [apply filters or item-level targeting](http://blogs.technet.com/b/grouppolicy/archive/2009/07/30/security-filtering-wmi-filtering-and-item-level-targeting-in-group-policy-preferences.aspx)?
- Do you see errors/warnings in the application eventlog?

If that doesn't help, try again with [debug logging enabled](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/07/18/enabling-group-policy-preferences-debug-logging-using-the-rsat.aspx).